# Is there a StackTraceElement[] equivalent of Throwable.printStackTrace()?

Tags: java

[Throwable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) has the method [printStackTrace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29) which prints a nicely formated stack trace. Is there some function which does the same for an array of [StackTraceElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) which can for example be obtained by calling [getAllStackTraces()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces%28%29)?

```
public static Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> getAllStackTraces()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The point of my question is: is there something already existing.

AFAIK, no.  Certainly there isn't anything in the standard Java SE libraries to do this.

(That's easy to check.  Go to the javadoc page for `StackTraceElement` and look at the "Uses" cross-reference.  If there were any public methods to render stack element arrays, they should show up there.)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the toString() method of StackTraceElement, it prints out the same way as printStackTrace does. You just have to concatenate the generated strings (foreach element of your array).

Comment: getAllStackTraces is a function, it does not have a toString method. The toString function of the returned map prints does not look like printStackTrace at all: "{Thread[Reference Handler,10,system]=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@b8aff, Thread[Signal Dispatcher, ..."

Comment: Sorry I meant the toString() method of StackTraceElement, of course…

Comment: Well yes, it returns a single element of the stack trace. I can (and have) manually build a String from those. The point of my question is: is there something already existing.

Comment: Well then I'm afraid not. Writing two lines instead of calling one method isn't that big a deal imho.